# Get 'highestCommittedUSN' attribute of a Domain Controller via LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory

I am currently working on a PHP script that will be polling Active Directory to pick out modified objects (people/users), via LDAP.

I'm able to filter on `uSNChanged` when I have the value, like so:

```
$previousUsn = '1234';
$ldapCon = ldap_connect('ldap-host');
$ldapBind = ldap_bind($ldapCon, 'ldap-user', 'ldap-password');
$sr = ldap_search($ldapCon, "ou=Users,dc=foo", "uSNChanged >= $previousUsn");
```

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676895.aspx), I should be able to retrieve a `highestCommittedUSN` attribute that  could be used for the initial run of the script. I've been looking around to find out how this can be done using PHP & LDAP, but to no avail.

Alternatively, feel free to suggest completely different methods of retrieving changes in AD.

Comment: ...and `$sr = ldap_search($ldapCon, "ou=Users,dc=foo", "highestCommittedUSN=*", array('highestCommittedUSN'));` doesn't get what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ldap_read(...)` seems to do the trick:

```
function getHighestCommittedUsn() {
    ldap_bind(...);
    $sr = ldap_read($ldapCon, null, "(highestcommittedusn=*)", array("highestcommittedusn"));
    $rs = ldap_get_entries($ldapCon, $sr);

    return $rs[0]["highestcommittedusn"][0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the search base (second argument) in your ldap_search call to `""`. That attribute is on a pseudo object called `RootDSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if the biffins function hasn't been initialised correctly? Hmmm try changing the variable type of c_willygham